# Google Drive Realtime API: doing atomic updates in a hierarchical data model while maintaining sort order

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm planning to build a todo app using the Google Drive Realtime API. It will have a hierarchical structure, so tasks can have sub-tasks, which can have sub-tasks, etc. A task can be moved around freely, which means it's position/index between it's siblings can change, but it's also possible to move it to another parent.

Now I know you have to take care on making these moves atomic when using the Realtime API. In a video Google engineers explain that the best way to do this is to have a flat representation of your hierarchical model: each item/tasks has a property that points to it's parent. This way moving a task to another parent takes just one operation: changing the parent property (instead of removing it from a child list of one parent and adding it to the child list of the new parent: two operation > not atomic).

This can work fine for my project, except that I also need to maintain the order of the child tasks within a parent tasks. How can I do this when a task only knows it's parent?
many thanks, Ruben

Answer (score 0):

I think this should work: have each task point to its parent task, as recommended. In addition, have each task keep a sorted list of its child tasks. Then, when you display a list of child tasks to the user, filter out the ones that don't point back to the correct parent. You'll occasionally have the same task under multiple parents, but the user will never see it.

The danger would be that, due to a race condition, you end up having a task that is not listed in any other task's list of children, but I think that can't happen.

Another way would be to have each task store a "sort order" value, which is a real number. The UI sorts them before displaying. If two users add tasks at the same location, there is a risk of them getting the same value, but it shouldn't really matter since the order of the two tasks isn't well defined in that case.